# Where is Web Deploy's httpHandler configured?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, web-deployment, msdeploy

I verified that I have installed Web Deploy 3.5 and I can see the Web Management Service running in services.

When I attempt to deploy to this service with VS 2010 or msdeploy.exe on the command-line, even locally, to https://servername.com:8172/Msdeploy.axd?site=mySite, I get a 404 returned from IIS.

It is my suspicion that I should see the httpHandler among those listed in the .NET 4.0 Web.config, but I do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web deployment handler is installed by Web Deploy which needs to be installed onto the server. You can find the installer at http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy with a couple of installer options available. Make sure you include the "IIS 7 Deployment Handler" when you install it. From there you'll probably want to take a look at [this article](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler) which explains how to get the correct permissions to the correct user accounts.

There's nothing in your project web.config that would be required to make it work. That's why the deployment handler is available on a separate port (8172).